# prevent events firing for overlapping HTML elements

Tags: jquery, events, delegates

So, I've got two elements, one nested within the other

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The outer container is larger than the inner, effecting a modal overlay layout. I want to register a click event on the exposed surface of the outer that will cause both to be dismissed, but I do not want this to occur if you click on the inner div.

I'm using jQuery delegate/stopPropagation, and trying to interrogate the element to ensure it's the outer div, but to no avail - it still recieves the outer event. I'm considering hand cranking in a hit area outside the inner div, but I want to know if there's a more elegant alternative.

EDIT:

several good solutions posted here - many thanks for feedback!

Comment: Please post the jQuery you've tried.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$("#inner").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  // do something
});
```

here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/fA2sd/1/

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#outer').on('click', function (e) {
    if ( e.target != this) return;
    // run your code here...
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9sLCx/

Comment: Nice. I'm using this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The event object as two properties that will help you for this task:

event.currentTarget identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element the event handler has been attached to as opposed to event.target which identifies the element on which the event occurred.
The event notification will pass for the outer div two times, first in the capture phase and later in the bubbling phase, in the middle if you instantiate a handler in the inner div it will be notified. You can stop the propagation when you want.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/hmariod/dvV4E/

```
document.getElementById("outer").addEventListener('click',etvFn,true);
document.getElementById("outer").addEventListener('click',etvFn,false);
document.getElementById("inner").addEventListener('click',etvFn,true);
document.getElementById("inner").addEventListener('click',etvFn,false);
document.getElementById("innerP").addEventListener('click',etvFn);

function etvFn(evt){
    var phase;
    if(evt.eventPhase === 1){
        phase = "Capture";
    }else if(evt.eventPhase === 2){
        phase = "Target";
    }else{
        phase = "Bubbling";
    }
    alert("Target:" + evt.target.id + "\nCurrent Target:" + evt.currentTarget.id + "\nPhase:" + phase);
}​
```